# how to detect the android back click using JavaScript/reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, android-webview, progressive-web-apps

I want to detect the android back click using JavaScript/react js in mobile web-view.

**Current Code:**

```
componentDidMount()  {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

 onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }

onBackKeyDown=()=>{
console.log("oBackKeyDown");}
```

**What I have Tried:**

1) adding event listener like

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false)
```

2) Then This

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e) {
  // ...
})
```

Nothing seems to be working.

I wanted console to print BackKeyDown but nothing is happening.

**Question:**

Is there was a to do this in pure JavaScript or in reactJS (without react native features like react navigation etc)?

Thanks.

Comment: I am using react ui-router for transition. If that have any feature to detect the android back, also will be helpful.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Not exactly, I am maintaining navigation history, using that detecting the back button on "popstate"

Answer (score 0):

`popstate` listener will detect  back button pressed but it will also detect forward button pressed.

`window.addEventListener("popstate", (e)=>{
    console.log("back button pressed);
})`

Comment: Yeah, i have tried this too. popstate will give the callback for url change. I want callback for android back key particularity.